# Stop debugging, but keep running app (VS2008 asp.net web app)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

If I start running my asp.net WebForms app from the VS2008 IDE in debug mode, is there a way I can tell it to then quit the debugging but keep on running? Often times, I start in debug mode, then after I'm done with the debugging, I want it to keep on running, but to come out of debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in the Debug menu to detach the deubgger ("Detach All").

This will detach the debugger and leave the debugged application running.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Debug > Detach All in the menu in VS2008 (Express edition, at least).

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, Debug -> Detach should work. As an alternative, if you set up your project to run on your local IIS instead of visual studio's defualt web server, your site should stay open after you stop your debugger. In the Web tab of the properties for your web application project there is an option to use the local IIS or a custom server instead of the default visual studio one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug -> Attach to process.
2. Select aspnet_wp process and click Attach.
3. Set breakpoints, debug.
4. When done debugging, Debug -> Detach from process