# VS : Shutting the debugger but Keeping Application Form Open

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My Application displays processing results on my main form (charts/visual reports).
I am in the debugging phase, so I need to interpret the outputs of the App, and make changes to the code based on these outputs.

The behavior I would like is to basically stop debugging (detach the debugger from the running thread I've launched), so i can change/edit the code, but keep the output forms open, As I need them to analyze reports and make the needed code changes.

PS : I have x64 outputs so there is no hot-code-edit-and-continue option (besides, this is not what I am looking for.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like TDD optima forma: Try Driven Development :-)

Comment: Running a separate instance is probably not what you want?

Comment: This one has solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422592/stop-debugging-but-keep-running-app-vs2008-asp-net-web-app

Comment: @rene no running a separate instance is not very convenient. I do need to debug at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

menu `Debug -> Detach all`
Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422592/stop-debugging-but-keep-running-app-vs2008-asp-net-web-app)

Comment: ThanX. I was sure that there was some untedious straighforward way to this. in French we say "Simple comme Bonjour" :-) That was perfect

Comment: Just for the record I DID search SOF BEFORE asking, but did not stumble on that post. Thanx for ur insight.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to run the EXE by double clicking on it and then attach the debugger using Debug->Attach To Process or Tool->Attach To Process.

So when you disconnect the debugger, it will carry on running.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your application without debugging, then attach the debugger, then  detach it when you're done, it won't close your app. The problem is that when you'll want to test your changes you need to do everything again which is a bit tedious.